# Não era para estar se movimentando?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

O meu objetivo seria fazer como se fosse "ondas" dentro do h2. Eu já tentei fazer de tudo mas não consigo, tentei fazer um @keyframes:

```
@keyframes animate {
 clip-path: polygon(0 47%, 19% 48%, 34% 56%, 55% 61%, 79% 59%, 98% 50%, 100% 
 99%, 0 100%);
}
```

Porém não consegui o resultado é apenas o "Water" parado com uma parte em azul.
A seguir está meu código:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicewidth, initial-scale">
    <title>Água</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="liquid">
        <h2>Water</h2>
        <h2>Water</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.liquid {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #183954;
}

.liquid h2 {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 26vh;
}

.liquid h2:nth-child(1) {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #183954,
    -4px 4px 0px #183954,
    -6px 6px 0px #183954,
    -8px 8px 0px #183954,
    -18px 18px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    -18px 18px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.liquid h2:nth-child(2) {
    color: #2196f3;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 46%, 16% 45%, 34% 52%, 50% 61%, 68% 65%, 85% 61%, 100% 53%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%0);
}
```

Alguma dica de como arrumar isto?